# Cannot open mailbox

Tags: outlook-2010, exchange-2013

Ive got a server running Windows Server 2012 and Exchange 2013 on my local domain. Ive got the mailboxes setup and can send/receive emails fine when using OWA.

If i try to open the mailbox using Outlook 2010, I get the below error
[image: Screenshot]

If i try to expand the folder, i get the same message but am still able to use OWA.

When I try to run a send/receive, I get the below error:
[image: http://imgur.com/FbjdXmB]

After a bit of researching on the web, people suggest that the profile is corrupt. I have recreated the profile and tried again but still same error.

Another post has suggested that the issue is DNS and client PCs should be able to resolve autodiscover.domain.local and server.domain.local to the IP of the server. This is fine on my network.

Every user has got the same issue and I am struggling to identify what is causing the fault.

Advise appreciated.

Comment: We need more detail from you in order to even take guesses at what the problem might be.

Comment: Ive edited the question to include a bit more info. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution

1. Create new windows profile and try to configure outlook
2. Disable proxy settings or put your Exchange CAS server in the proxy exceptions list

Answer (score 0):

Please provide output for the following commands:

```
Get-OutlookAnywhere | FT
Get-ClientAccessServer | FT
Get-OutlookProvider
```